# Value of type `Vec<&str>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=&&str>`

Tags: rust

Why does this code work properly

```
fn main() {
let v1 = vec!["lemonade", "lemon", "type", "lid"];
println!("{:?}", v1.iter().filter(|item| item.starts_with("l")).collect::<Vec<_>>());
}
```

While this code gets me an error, I kinda get the sense why this isn't working and I get how to fix it, but I don't really understand what type is it returning so I can replace the "_" to something not that generic

```
fn main() {
let v1 = vec!["lemonade", "lemon", "type", "lid"];
println!("{:?}", v1.iter().filter(|item| item.starts_with("l")).collect::<Vec<&str>>());
}
```

The error

```
error[E0277]: a value of type `Vec<&str>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of 
type `&&str`
--> src\main.rs:3:69
 |
 3    |     println!("{:?}", v1.iter().filter(|item| item.starts_with("l")).collect:: 
 <Vec<&str>>());
 |                                                                     ^^^^^^^ value of type 
 `Vec<&str>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=&&str>`
 |
 = help: the trait `FromIterator<&&str>` is not implemented for `Vec<&str>`
 = help: the trait `FromIterator<T>` is implemented for `Vec<T>`
 note: required by a bound in `collect`
--> C:\Users\Mululi\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows- 
 msvc\lib/rustlib/src/rust\library\core\src\iter\traits\iterator.rs:1788:19
 |
 1788 |     fn collect<B: FromIterator<Self::Item>>(self) -> B
 |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `collect`
```

I couldn't fully understand what the compiler meant by that

Answer (score 6):

##### Explaining the error

Let's look at the types in detail. It will take a couple of documentation derefs to get to the bottom so bear with me.

> ```
> let v1 = vec!["lemonade", "lemon", "type", "lid"];
> ```

`v1` is a `Vec<&str>`.

> ```
> v1.iter()
> ```

`Vec` doesn't have an `iter` method, but it implements `Deref<Target = [T]>` [which does](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.iter):

```
pub fn iter(&self) -> Iter<'_, T>
```

`Iter` here is a struct named [`std::slice::Iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html). What kind of iterator is it? We need to take a look at its [`Iterator` implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html#associatedtype.Item):

```
impl<'a, T> Iterator for Iter<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a T;
}
```

This tells us that the iterator yields item of type `&T`. Remember that we have a `Vec<&str>`, so `T = &str`. That means that what we really have is an `Iterator<Item = &&str>`. That's the source of the error you're getting.

#### Fixes

So, how do we get an `Iterator<Item = &str>` instead of an `Iterator<Item = &&str>`? There are several ways, including:

##### 1. `into_iterator()`

Use `Vec`'s [implementation of `IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-IntoIterator-1) which has `Item = T`. `into_iterator()` yields `T`s instead of `&T`s.

```
v1.into_iter().filter(...)
```

This is efficient, but note that it consumes the vector. It doesn't return an iterator that *references* the items, it actually moves the items out of the vector and into the consuming code. The vector is unuseable after calling `into_iter`.

##### 2. `iter().copied()`

If `T: Copy` you can call [`copied`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.copied) to turn an `Iterator<Item = &T>` into an `Iterator<Item = T>`.

```
v1.iter().copied().filter(...)
```

This technique is great because it doesn't consume the vector, and it will work because `&str` is indeed `Copy`. All references are `Copy` thanks to this [blanket implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html#impl-Copy-91):

```
impl<T: ?Sized> Copy for &T {}
```

##### 3. `iter().cloned()`

If `T: Clone` you can call [`cloned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cloned) to clone all the items and turn an `Iterator<Item = &T>` into an `Iterator<Item = T>`.

```
v1.iter().cloned().filter(...)
```

Anything that's `Copy` is also `Clone`, so you could indeed clone the `&str` references.

Answer (score 0):

You need to collect into `Vec<&&str>`, not `Vec<&str>`. The original vector is `Vec<&str>`, and `iter()` produces an iterator over references to the elements, so the iterator yields `&&str`s.